# Admob Ads on every 4th Fragments Open

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display admob ads on every 4th Fragment open by user. I am trying to do it as like below

I have made variable in My constant file like below

`public static int ad_count = 4;`

I am declaring this in every fragments view created like below

`constant.ad_count = constant.ad_count-1;`

and for display ads I am using method like below

```
private void showInterstitial() {


    if(constant.ad_count== 0) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
        //showAd();
    }
}
```

This is showing every time ads instead of every 4th Fragment open. Can anyone help me for solve my issue that what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: increment ad_count every time, but call showAd() only if ad_count %4 == 0; % - modulo operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @user1516873 I need +1 every time instead of -1 ? Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you increase or decrease the value as long as you use modulo for deciding on showing the ad, but increasing seems more natural